# Groovy Nested IF condition inside FOR loop is not checking the "else if" statement

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to return the HTML values in my groovy script from the list and checking if the condition is met, where the code is not checking the `else if` condition and only returning `if` condition's return value.

Is there something I am missing?

```
def groups = ["test","test1","test2","test3"]

  for(group in groups) {        //looping list
    if(group=="test") {
        html= """
        <input type="checkbox" json="TEST" name="value" value="TEST">
        <label for="TEST">TEST</label>
        """
          return html
    }
    else if(group=="test1") {
             html2="""
        <input type="checkbox" json="TEST1" name="value" value="TEST1">
        <label for="TEST1">TEST1</label>
            """  
        return html2
    }
  }
```

Comment: First of all, there is a missing closing `"` after test2? Next, this code works just fine with plain groovy, although it will always return the result from the first if. It's great, if you simplify your code to focus on the actual problem, but right now there is no problem and the problem most likely the actual problem around all this.  Also it would help if you would add a clear problem statement as to what is not working.

Comment: No suspense here... The `return html`will exit the loop/function as soon as "test" is found in groups. The rest of the array will not be processed. Nor clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @IanW/@cfrik, I am trying to return the values which are being matched in the ```if``` and ```else if``` statements. if its not matched then it should not return..

Comment: But as soon as you get a match, the first one, you return and you are done processing. That's different to returning all the values that match (in aggregate). For that, you'd have to declare "html=" outside the loop and aggregate the content to "html".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, since you return in each of the if branches, your code stop after the first iteration.

What you are looking for is a `collect`, that iterates a collection and returns that collection transformed into something else based on the given closure:

```
def groups = ["test","test1","test2","test3"]

def html_list = groups.collect { group ->
    if (group == "test") {
        return """<input type="checkbox" json="TEST" name="value" value="TEST">
        <label for="TEST">TEST</label>"""
    } else if (group == "test1") {
        return """<input type="checkbox" json="TEST1" name="value" value="TEST1">
        <label for="TEST1">TEST1</label>""" 
    }
  }.grep()
  
println html_list
```

The `grep()` in the end is just to get rid of the `null`s in the end, since the two lists aren't the same size for this example. To avoid it you could have something like this:

```
def groups = ["test","test1","test2","test3"]

def html_list = groups.collect { group ->
    def test_name = group.toUpperCase()
    return """<input type="checkbox" json="${test_name}" name="value" value="${test_name}">
    <label for="${test_name}">${test_name}</label>"""
}

println html_list
```